# Django filter query on with property fields automatically calculated

Tags: python, django, django-models

There is Django Order model with property fields automatically calucated. How to do a filter query.

```
class Order(models.Model):

    @property
    def expire(self):
        return self.created + datetime.timedelta(days=self.days_left())

    @property
    def days_left(self):
        return self.recurrence_period  * self._recurrence_unit_days[self.recurrence_unit]
```

Calculation done to get 1,3,7 datetime days from today

```
settings.SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRATION_REMIND = [1, 3, 7]

days = map(lambda x: datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=x), settings.SUBSCRIPTION_EXPIRATION_REMIND)

[datetime.date(2015, 7, 28),
 datetime.date(2015, 7, 30),
 datetime.date(2015, 8, 3)]
```

How to filter by ORM query

```
Order.objects.filter(expire__in=days)
```

Django is throwing error.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'expire' into field.
```

Comment: i thought, i knew it is not possible, but how to get around it

Answer (score -15, accepted):

Ended up adding expire to model, calculating the value on save method. Now i can do

```
 Order.objects.filter(expire__in=days)
```

Comment: This is not a solution.

Comment: 'expire' is not a actual field of model in db layer! so it can not be resolved by django. absolutely not works.

Comment: `expire` can be computed, this is not the solution to this, you can get the created date and do a range query

Comment: you can't perform lookup based on model methods or properties.

Answer (score 56):

**No, you can't perform lookup based on model methods or properties. Django ORM does not allow that.**

Queries are compiled to SQL to be sent and processed at the database level whereas properties are Python code and the database knows nothing about them. That's the reason why the  Django filter only allows us to use database fields.

**Can do this:**

```
Order.objects.filter(created=..) # valid as 'created' is a model field
```

**Cannot do this:**

```
Order.objects.filter(expires=..) # INVALID as 'expires' is a model property
```

You can instead use list comprehensions to get the desired result.

```
[obj for obj in Order.objects.all() if obj.expire in days]
```

The above will give me the list of `Order` objects having `expire` value in the `days` list.

Comment: keep getting error implementing it. KeyError: None
even though their are records

Comment: It should work, please recheck if there are records in the db. Try putting a debugger and see if anything is missing and where exactly you get the `KeyError`.

Comment: I did use the list per you recommendations. But it donot perform  filtering correctly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649078/how-to-filter-on-calculated-model-values-using-list-comprehension

Comment: It's important to note that by using the list comprehension, you're forcing evaluation and now your data type is `list`, not `QuerySet`.  This won't work, in many cases, for example, `get_queryset()` methods.

Comment: I would elaborate a little bit @TaylorEdmiston comment, that iterating over `QuerySet` object (here `Order.objects.all()`) will force the database to walk through all the existed records in the `Order` table. Due to performance reason, it is totally not acceptable. If you wanna query the DB by model's methods or properties it is case to think of making them the model's fields with DB index accordingly

Answer (score 4):

I dont think you can use a property in the field lookups as the doc says `The field specified in a lookup has to be the name of a model field` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups