# Append value to object using list comprehension

Tags: python, django

I am using django and due to some limitations of Django framework had to use   list comprehension to filter values in my model.

My current statement is following

```
 po_list = [n for n in Material.objects.all() if ((F('total_inventory') + F('total_po') - F('total_so')) < F('min_quantity'))]
```

What I want to achieve is not just to return the filtered list but also to add a new column to n that will include the calculated values. (I don't want to redo those calculations again in template the goal is to have calculation done in one place only)

So it should be something like this

```
   po_list = [n+[F(max_quantity) - total_inv] for n in Material.objects.all()  deficit = (F('total_inventory') + F('total_po') - F('total_so')) total_inv = (F('total_inventory') + F('total_po') - F('total_so')) if (total_inv < F('min_quantity'))]
```

I struggle with 3 things

- 1-Is it possible
- 2-Sintaxis- how to code  it correctly
- 3-if it is possible how I name the new field I added to object - I
  need to access it somehow in the template

Comment: No, add something as field to object which will be passed to newly created list is impossible EXCEPT case when `add as field` operation return new/modified object. But anyway, I reviewed your code and could say that list comprehension will not be pythonic here. It is too hard to read such complex oneliner.

Comment: You're probably looking in the wrong direction here. For database aggregation in django look here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values

Comment: Thank you for answers, what brought me to this decision is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649078/how-to-filter-on-calculated-model-values-using-list-comprehension?noredirect=1#comment62778445_37649078  I dont know how can I do it any diffrent and more pythonic

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't try to do this with a list comprehension. What your looking for is database aggregation. Django supports this to some extent. Some more information can be found in the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#values

You should add a `values` call to the queryset which contains the fields you want to group by. After that add an `annotate` to perform the required aggregation per grouped set of objects.

Comment: Thanks but I have been there- it doesn't work since my fields are properties See my previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37649078/how-to-filter-on-calculated-model-values-using-list-comprehension?noredirect=1#comment62778445_37649078

Comment: In that case the solution would (sadly) be to not use properties or simple put it in a for-loop. Using a for-loop can be more readable and nicer than a list comprehension.

Comment: Hi all, I am still confused how to move forward with this. I have tested the output and realized that list comprehension I wrote not always giving the correct output . For loop will be may be cleaner but it is really exactly same thing as the list comprehension just written differently,any answer will be super helpful .