# Django faster loading of form

Tags: python, django

I have a `model` named `Title`, which contains some `ForeignKey` fields:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')
    rank = models.ForeignKey('Title_rank')
```

I have a `form` that has parameter `choices` set to all of the `Title` entries:

```
class Emp_titleForm(forms.Form):

    title = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                choices=( (x.id, x.department.name + " - " + x.name) for x in Titles.objects.all() ),
                widget=forms.SelectMultiple(),
                required=True,
            )
```

The page loads fine but is slow (~6-10sec) from (I assume) there being many objects in the `Title` class (currently ~5,000).

Is there anyway to adjust my **`form`** or **`model`** to speed up page load? Unfortunately, filtering to reduce choices is not an option.  Also, note that I would like to display the `department` with the `title` (e.g.: "Dept - Title")

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> (x.id, x.name) for x in Titles.objects.all()
> ```

Instead of looping over all `Title` objects, try a more efficient query:

```
Title.objects.values_list('id', 'name')
```

Edit:

To combine fields, assuming you are using Django 1.8+, you can do the following:

```
from django.db.models import Concat, Value
Title.objects.annotate(
    department_name=Concat('department__name', Value(' - '), 'name')
).values_lists('id', 'department_name')
```

Comment: Nice thank you.  Is there any way I can combine `name` and `department` into the `values_list`?  The results would then be: `(x.id, x.department.name + " - " + x.name) for x in Titles.objects.all()`.  I have updated the question to describe this.

Comment: Damn, I am using Django 1.7 :(.  But +1 for answer; thank you.  Maybe there is a way to leverage the `def __unicode__` function within a `model`?

Answer (score 0):

The standard Django approach (not version dependent) to solving this is to create a property in your **Title** model:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')
    rank = models.ForeignKey('Title_rank')

    @property
    def department_name(self):
        return u'%s-%s' % (self.department, self.name)
```

You can then reference this directly in your form. Good luck.

**UPDATE**

As noted in the comments, you cannot perform lookups on model properties. You will first need to add this field to your model using the save() method, then you can do the filter:

```
class Title(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    department = models.ForeignKey('Department')
    rank = models.ForeignKey('Title_rank')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.department_name = u'%s-%s' % (self.department, self.name)
        super(Title, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Looks like django doesn't support this?  http://stackoverflow.com/a/31659633/4245462

Comment: Thanks @NickBraunagel - Updated answer to add the field using the save() method.