# Django filter users by is_active and has_usable_password() method

Tags: django, django-models

I have a user manager which has a method to create users without password. Now, I need to get all unactivated users which is `user.is_active=False` and `user.has_usable_password()=False`.

Django doc link for [has_usable_password()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_usable_password).

I wan't to do something like below.

```
User.objects.filter(is_active=False, password__has_usable_password=False)
```

Comment: What is the actual question/requirement?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I specified it as `I wan't to do something like below`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`has_usable_password` is not stored in DB, so you cannot use it in queryset directly, istead you can check if password startwith `!` or empty:

```
from django.db.models import Q
User.objects.filter(Q(is_active=False), Q(password__startswith='!') | Q(password__isnull=True))
```

This is exactly what `has_usable_password` do ([source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/hashers.py#L23)).

Comment: getting `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'startwith' for CharField or join on the field not permitted.`

Comment: @bkmagnetron sorry it type should be `startswith`.

Comment: can I do simply this `User.objects.filter(is_active=False, password__startswith='!')`

Comment: @bkmagnetron in this case you will missed records with password=Null. So You'd better add `password__isnull=True`

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue but is there a way to do something like `User.objects.filter(is_active=False, self__has_usable_password=False)` i.e. accessing objects own method.

Comment: @bkmagnetron no, it's not possible. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658793/django-filter-query-on-with-property-fields-automatically-calculated