# How to filter Django queryset by model property?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have a method in my django app model like below:

```py
@property
def invoice_id(self):
    """
    Represent the invoice object in __str__ format BELLA-17-08-20-2
    :return:
    """
    day_list = []
    invoice_list = Invoice.objects.filter(
        timestamp__year=self.timestamp.year, \
        timestamp__month=self.timestamp.month, \
        timestamp__day=self.timestamp.day
    ).all()

    for invoice in invoice_list:
        day_list.append(invoice.id)
        position = 0

        for i in day_list:
            if i == self.id:
                invoice_id = 'BELLA-' + self.timestamp.strftime("%d-%m-%y") + '-' + str(position + 1)
                return invoice_id

            position += 1
```

I want to filter in my `views.py` like :

```
queryset = Invoice.objects.filter(
    Q(pro_id=.......)
)
```

How can I do this ?? Any Suggestion ??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django filter query on with property fields automatically calculated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31658793/django-filter-query-on-with-property-fields-automatically-calculated)

Comment: Issue Solved ..Thanks for your reply

Comment: @barii how do you solve the issue?